# WinAppDriver can't install properly

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, winappdriver

I have a problem in how to config the WinAppDriver, it's not identifying the OpenQA.Selenium.Appium.Windows;

Not found on nuget package manager, and I need help how solve this issue.

```
    [SetUp]
    public void TestInit()
    {
        var appCapabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
        appCapabilities.SetCapability("app", @"Microsoft.MicrosoftStickyNotes_8wekyb3d8bbwe!App");
        appCapabilities.SetCapability("deviceName", "WindowsPC");
        driver = new WindowsDriver(new Uri("http://127.0.0.1:4723"), appCapabilities);
        driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
    }
```

> Error  CS0103  The name 'driver' does not exist in the current context UnitTestProject2    C:\Users\danie\source\repos\UnitTestProject2\UnitTestProject2\UnitTest.cs   21  Active
>
> Error  CS0305  Using the generic type 'WindowsDriver' requires 1 type arguments UnitTestProject2    C:\Users\danie\source\repos\UnitTestProject2\UnitTestProject2\UnitTest.cs   21  Active
>
> Error  CS0103  The name 'driver' does not exist in the current context UnitTestProject2    C:\Users\danie\source\repos\UnitTestProject2\UnitTestProject2\UnitTest.cs   22  Active

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void setUp() 
{
    try {
        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
        capabilities.setCapability("app", "C:\\Program Files\\test\\test.exe");
        capabilities.setCapability("platformName","Windows");
        capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "WindowsPC");
        whatfixSession = new WindowsDriver<WindowsElement>(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723"), capabilities);
        whatfixSession.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: HI. Thank you for your contribution. Could you please add some context that would make it easier for subsequent readers to follow along?